# Clock program using Java (JApplet)

Tags: java, applet, user-input, clock

I am completely stumped as to where I am going wrong with my clock program.

My program is supposed to accept user input for hours and minutes. The user's input would then set the hour-hand and the minute-hand to its appropriate position on the drawn out circular clock in a pop-up window.

My program doesn't seem to take in user input but instead it takes in input from the paint method in `ClockApplet.java`. I'm not quite sure how to make my program take in input from the user instead. Any advice/input/help would be greatly appreciated!

My code is as follows:

**Clock.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Clock
{
public Clock()
{
    this.anHour=12;
    this.aMin=0;
}

public Clock(double hr, double min)
{
    this.anHour=hr;
    this.aMin=min;
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;

    Ellipse2D.Double clock_face = new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 2 * RADIUS, 
                                    2 * RADIUS);
    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(clock_face);

    Point2D.Double center=new Point2D.Double(RADIUS, RADIUS);
    double angle=Math.PI /2 - 2 * Math.PI * aMin / MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
    Point2D.Double minutePoint=new Point2D.Double(RADIUS + MINUTE_HAND
                                * Math.cos(angle), RADIUS - MINUTE_HAND * Math.sin(angle));
    Line2D.Double minuteHand=new Line2D.Double(center, minutePoint);
    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(minuteHand);

    angle=Math.PI / 2 - 2 * Math.PI * (anHour * MINUTES_PER_HOUR +
            aMin) / (MINUTES_PER_HOUR * HOURS_PER_DAY);
    Point2D.Double hourPoint=new Point2D.Double(RADIUS + HOUR_HAND *
                                Math.cos(angle), RADIUS - HOUR_HAND * Math.sin(angle));
    Line2D.Double hourHand=new Line2D.Double(center, hourPoint);
    ((Graphics2D) g).draw(hourHand);

    Clock clock1=new Clock(anHour, aMin);
}

private double anHour;
private double aMin;

final double RADIUS = 100;
final double MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;
final double HOURS_PER_DAY = 12;
final double HOUR_HAND = 75;
final double MINUTE_HAND = 90;
}
```

**ClockApplet.java**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * This applet draws the clock shape.
 */

public class ClockApplet extends JApplet
{
    public ClockApplet()
    {
        String input;

    input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the time (hh:mm):","Clock Applet", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if((input==null) || (input.equals("")))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input", "Alert", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int colon1=input.indexOf(":");
        int colon2=input.lastIndexOf(":");

        double hours=findHour(colon1, input);
        double minutes=findMin(colon2, input);

        if(hours!=0 && minutes!=0)
        {
            Clock clock1=new Clock(hours, minutes);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input", "Alert", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public double findHour(int colon1, String input)
{
    String userHour=input.substring(colon1+1);
    double aHour=Double.parseDouble(userHour);
    double temp1=0.0;

    if(aHour>0 && aHour<=12)
    {
        temp1=aHour;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return temp1;
}

public double findMin(int colon2, String input)
{
    String userMin=input.substring(colon2+1);
    double aMin=Double.parseDouble(userMin);
    double temp1=0.0;

    if(aMin>0 && aMin<=60)
    {
        temp1=aMin;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return temp1;
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;

    Clock clock1=new Clock(10,10);

    clock1.draw(g2);

}

}
```

**ClockApplet.html**

```
<applet code="ClockApplet.class" width="50" height="50"> </applet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the code that accepts user input into the `life cycle` method of the `applet`.So add the code to init() method of the applet, but I think it is missing here.So oberride init() method and add the code:

```
 @Override
    public void init(){
    input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the time (hh:mm):","Clock Applet", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I quite understand. >_<

Comment: @xGiraffe, you need to go through how applet works and its life cycle methods.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html.In this case, an applet takes its own life once its init() method is fired.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the parsing of the hour.  If the time is specified as `05:15` as prompted, it gets the wrong substring.  Do statements like this:

```
System.out.println(/* the object I now have */);
```

..as it passes through the `findHour()` method, to check what is happening.  Alternately, use a debugger.